# Google Chrome Extension Tab URL - How do I make it global?

Tags: javascript, api, url, google-chrome-extension

I am using the following code:

```
                                                                      //popup.js
var myUrl;
chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) {
    myURL = tab.url;    
    }); 
 console.log('my url is ' + myUrl);
```

And in the console I get:

```
my url is undefined
```

I want the value of myURL to be the user's current url, but I am not sure what I am doing wrong here. I have tried different variations, including a return, but that had not worked.

Comment: You should understand the asynchronous concept. The callback function will be evaluated later than console.log. Place the log into the {} brackets.

Comment: I see what you mean! I will have to study this concept more, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Much like Skalar Wag said, the timing seems to be my problem.

I wanted to test that the variable was passed, because I was using in other segments of the code. I have resolved this concern and my application worked out great, thanks!